# Extract URL of CSV data from webpage

Tags: web-scraping

it seems to me as if onvista has recently changed its website design. My former links to retrieve stock market data do not work anymore. Unfortunately, I am not able to extract the URL of the CSV data from that website, for example:

https://www.onvista.de/index/boersenkurse/DAX-Kursindex-Index-1966970

EDIT: This is what I did so far:

`link = paste0("https://www.onvista.de/onvista/boxes/historicalquote/export.csv?notationId=",onvista.ID,"&dateStart=",mday(aktuell),".",month(aktuell),".",year(aktuell),"&interval=M1")`

`temp = read.csv2(url(link))`

Can someone of you help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us your code, what have you tried until now? And that csv button does not contain a link: it generates the csv on the fly, from that datatables.

Comment: I've included the former code above. But the link I use does not exist any more. Is there a possibility to read out the data even if the cdv is generated on the fly? All I need is exactly the csv data table which is generated by clicking the button "Download als CSV".

Comment: what language is this?